# What does UNC path with @SSL tucked to the hostname mean?

Tags: sharepoint, unc

I got some links in the form `\\internal.sharepoint.company.tld@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\123456\...` from colleague. Due to Convoluted™ setup¹ I can't directly access them.

- What does the `@SSL` mean here? Normally in URL the host part may be `user@host`, but in this case it is definitely hostname before the `@`.
- Can I translate it to a proper URL a non-Windows system would understand?

Comment: The site is a Microsoft SharePoint. I don't see a way to check which version.

Comment: The convoluted setup involves a VPN, a HTTP proxy, and careful configuration, because the sharepoint itself has to be accessed through the proxy, but the online document viewers are served from separate server which must not…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a SSL connection request over webdav protocol

[DavGetHTTPFromUNCPath function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/davclnt/nf-davclnt-davgethttpfromuncpath)

@ssl is a hardcoded keyword trick that instructs the WebDav redirector to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

DavWWWRoot it's the root path of the WebDav.

Comment: I was already thinking that. It leaves the question how does the system decide whether to access it over HTTP(S) or SMB though.